# Strange bug in different compilation mode

Tags: c#, debugging, compilation, release, fileinfo

I'm encountering a very strange bug which appears only when compiling in *Release* mode, while in *Debug* mode the code runs perfectly. Moreover, the bug is encountered only in one machine (a user reported this).

This is the stack trace:

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find file 'C:\Users...\FileName.txt'.
>   File name: 'C:\Users...\FileName.txt'
>      in System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>      in System.IO.FileInfo.get_Length()
>      in PatcherNET4.FileHandler.LocalFile.get_Size()
>      in PatcherNET4.FileHandler.CachedFile.IsLocalValid(LocalFile file)
>      in PatcherNET4.FileHandler.FileManager.<>c__DisplayClassd.b__9(CachedFile file)
>      in System.Linq.Enumerable.FirstOrDefault[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source, Func`2 predicate)
>      in PatcherNET4.FileHandler.FileManager.RemoveLocalFiles()
>      in PatcherNET4.FileHandler.FileManager.DownloadMissingFiles()
>      in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
>      in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
>      in System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
>      in System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

And this is the code:

```
// CachedFile
...
public bool IsLocalValid(LocalFile file)
{
    var checkName = file.Name == Name;
    var checkSize = file.Size == Size;
    var checkLastWrite = file.LastWriteTime == LastWriteTime;
    return checkName && checkSize && checkLastWrite;
}
...

//LocalFile
...
public uint Size
{
    get
    {
        _info.Refresh();
        return (uint)_info.Length;
    }
}
...
```

How is this possible? I can assure you that there is no difference in the interested pieces of code between the release and debug mode. I don't really know what to do, this is probably the strangest bug I've ever seen.

Comment: So does `C:\Users...\FileName.txt` exist on that machine?

Comment: Is the path relative? When you run in debug/release, the running directory for the program will be different.

Comment: Yes, it exists; moreover, the bug happened with two different files in two different runs

Comment: An error that depends only of the compiling mode smells like a running condition.

Comment: @tnw: yes, it is relative (thanks for this point, I'll try that tomorrow). But how is it possible that this bug is encountered only in one machine, while 200 and more people are using it? SJuan, for example?

Comment: I'd also like to understand why there are downvotes. Am I providing few informations? This is a strange case, I don't really know what to give you

Comment: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find file 'C:\Users...\FileName.txt'." *is* the error - that is, the file can't be found (which likely means the path is different/incorrect between good and bad running *environments*). Follow it back from there. Don't blame the compiler.

Comment: @user2864740, I tried. It has no sense (to me), the file is there.

Comment: Are you using a file called FileName.txt?

Comment: @LightStyle have u tried to remove (manually) all files from debug/release directories and ReBuild all projects?

Comment: @HackerMan what do you mean by "using"?
Lucas, yes, I tried everything I had in my head. Nothing worked. Only giving the user the program compiled in debug mode.

Comment: trying to open the file FileName.txt

Comment: No, it is not open while the program is running, but it's there

Answer (score 0):

put **FileName.txt** in the Unable to find **file 'C:\Users...\(here)   directory**

Comment: @LightStyle check the file name brother     System.IO.FileNotFoundException <----look carefully!

Comment: Already did. I'm not that stupid, don't worry. The file is there, and the program is not recognizing it. I also thought it could be a problem of the path (it contained a space inside of it), I made the user change it and it didn't work either.

Comment: Well, it's possible. But how do you explain that this "stupid program" works on 200+ machines without errors and it doesn't work **only in release mode** on a single machine?

Comment: It's possible. But I can't yet explain myself how it is possibly different the same program in Debug and Release mode.

Comment: @LightStyle if you use **current directory** in debug mode...you should use **absolute** location in release mode....ok

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd try is to verify the file exists at runtime and go from there.

```
if (!File.Exists(fileName))
{
    // do something
}
```

If the file doesn't exist (I believe you when you say it's missing) then consider the alternatives. Has the file been deleted already? I notice in the stacktrace there's RemoveLocalFiles, so perhaps it's already been run. Maybe a user pressed a button twice? race condition. Separate thread? User is logged in on two machines and has roaming profiles. Or something like that.

Regardless of whether it's a bug or not, it's better to be defensive and include a check to make sure the file exists (or catch the exception if that's your preference).